# Can´t display data QSqlQueryModel in a C++ QTableView from MySql Database

Tags: c++, mysql, qtableview

I don´t know what´s happening with this exemple.

My connection is ok.

The query results is ok ( see application output below )...but my qtableview is empty.

[results screen with 9 empty lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaEh5.jpg)

The application output shows 9 lines and these lines are the correct results from my table. The rowCount = 9...but the tableview is completely empty.

```
#include "pedidos.h"
#include "ui_pedidos.h"

Pedidos::Pedidos(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Pedidos)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Login conn;

    if(!conn.connOpen())
       ui->label_pedidos_conn->setText("Falha na conexão ao Database");
    else
       ui->label_pedidos_conn->setText("Database Ok");

}

Pedidos::~Pedidos()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Pedidos::on_pushButton_load_pedidos_clicked()
{
    Login conn;
    QSqlQueryModel *modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
    QTableView *view = new QTableView;

    conn.connOpen();

    QSqlQuery *qry=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

    qry->prepare("SELECT id_pedido,id_user FROM pedido WHERE status=0");
    qry->exec();
    modal->setQuery(*qry);

    modal->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Pedido");
    modal->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Usuário");

    ui->tableView_pedidos->setModel(modal); // empty

    view->setModel(modal);  // second window
    view->show();           // doesn´t work too ( empty )

    while(qry->next()){

        QString usuario = qry->value(0).toString();
        qDebug() << "id:" << usuario;
    }

    conn.connClose();
    qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());

}
```

My Application Output is here:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
Database Ok
name: "124"
name: "125"
name: "126"
name: "127"
name: "128"
name: "129"
name: "131"
name: "225"
name: "308"
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
9
```

Comment: I think the conn->connClose() should be removed

Comment: Yes!!!!! you are 100%  right.

Comment: I have posted the answer so if other people will try to find the solution they will find it. please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code that you have put there to debug is redundant and in partcular the conn->connClose() il closing the DB before the tableView could use it to fetch the data.

```
while(qry->next()){
    QString usuario = qry->value(0).toString();
    qDebug() << "id:" << usuario;
}
conn.connClose(); <---- remove this line!!!
qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());
```